# jcuda or cuda: pros and cons of over versus the other

Tags: java, c, cuda, gpu, jcuda

Me mother tongue is Java (I know I know, but you can't change who you are).

So I wanted to get a pros / cons of doing CUDA vs. JCUDA.

I just found out there is a [jcuda.org](http://www.jcuda.org/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cuda represents language extensions to C or C++ (or Fortran).  JCuda presents a binding API so that library calls and cuda functions written in C or C++ can be called from Java.  If you want to write java kernel code that runs on the GPU, you may also be interested in [root beer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1).

Comment: Oh wow, I'm glad I asked this question ... would never have discovered root beer on my own.

Comment: @RobertCrovella you may want to put your comment as an answer -- I'd then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cuda](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda) represents language extensions to C or C++ (or Fortran). [JCuda](http://jcuda.org) presents a binding API so that library calls (e.g. cublas for linear algebra, or cufft for fft's, etc.)  and arbitrary cuda functions written in C or C++ can be called from Java. If you want to write java kernel code that runs on the GPU, you may also be interested in [root beer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1).  Root beer allows you to write kernel code that runs on the thread processors in a GPU directly, without any requirement for CUDA C.  However, you'll still need to install the CUDA toolkit to enable the Root Beer "Java Compiler".